# How do i get access to a db, so i can get the organizations id?

Tags: django, database, dynamic, django-rest-framework, endpoint

I am working on creating notices for a particular app. And I need to make the API for this dynamic as I am collecting information from the db, not the models.py file.
Right now, I'm using dummy data so it works, but I need to get the organizations id from the db so it is dynamic. Any ideas how? ANY help would be appreciated!

```
class CreateNoticeAPIView(views.APIView):

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = CreateNotice(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            db.save("noticeboard", "613a1a3b59842c7444fb0220", serializer.data)
            return Response(
                {
                    "success":True, 
                    "data":serializer.data,
                    "message":"Successfully created"
                }, 
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(
            {
                "success":False, 
                "message":"Try again!"
            }, 
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

That's the view in the views.py file for creating the notices.
The second parameter in db.save is the dummy data for organization id (i.e "613a1a3b59842c7444fb0220").
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the model having organisation id.

Comment: There is none. Our models are directly from the db.That's why it is so much of a hassle.